# GAN and NN for sparse data

Tags: neural-networks, sparse, gan

I have a set of images which represent some correlated sparse data $x_1,\ldots ,x_n$. there are a number of specific pixels in the images which might hold value or not (with some probability), while the other pixels will always be 'off'.

Assuming I have calculated their correlation map, is there a way to learn the set of pixels using a GAN? I wish to generate in the output of a network, an image, where all the possible pixels are 'on'. I wish to do so from a minimal number of images $n$ in a set. Is there a good tutorial on how to handle with sparse data in neural networks or specifically but not limited to GANs?